# Recommendations roxy settings for MarkLogic 8 with dev, prod or local environment variables?

Tags: amazon-ec2, marklogic, marklogic-8, roxy

By default, there is three environment variables that can be run with ruby roxy configuration of a MarkLogic (the roxy script is here: https://github.com/marklogic/roxy). The three variables are: `local`, `dev` and `prod`. Although, others environment variables can be added.

What would be the best setup for `local`, `dev` and `prod` servers? The prod server is on an ec2 AWS.

I think, locally, there should only be 1 or 2 forests, and on a server maybe 1 or 2 forests for 4 cores. The forests can function in parallel. I think in the dev environment, tests should be run. Also, interested to know how much space the MarkLogic DB caches when run, both locally and on a ec2 instance.

I believe, by default the prod environment variable does run test (although that might be wrong).

Some information:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KCspJ-BP4T0
- https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/marklogic-on-aws.pdf
- https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/blob/master/deploy/default.properties
- https://github.com/marklogic/roxy/wiki/Environment-properties

Comment: The best setup depends on many variables, including the size and content of your data set and what you want to do with it. From what you've said so far, I'd start with the default settings and start playing around from there.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I enjoyed watching your youtube videos. They were very helpful. Would you possibly be able to point in the right direction for how to tailor MarkLogic settings for different content, particularly regarding semantics? I haven't found a good resource on database content.

I was hoping for some "rule of thumb" measurements, but you are right there is many variables, so it is hard to give definitive answers.

Comment: If you haven't already, I suggest reading [Inside MarkLogic Server](https://developer.marklogic.com/inside-marklogic). That will give a better understanding of the inner workings, which will give you a better sense of how to adjust the indexes. (Be aware that the current version of that paper was written for ML7; updated version is in the woks.) My other suggestion is more specific questions -- tell us about your data (give samples if possible) and what you want you want to do with it.

Comment: If your data is sample data to play with and learn from, that's okay. I have a MarkLogic application for beer recipes -- still useful for exploring.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Dave, best setup depends on many factors, but I'd add that nr forests primarily depends on the amount of data you'd like to load, and also on the response times, and loading speeds you seek. With the same amount of data, more forests will allow more parallelization of querying and ingestion. Once you reach limits in cpu, mem or disk speed, you scale out horizontally to allow for additional forests.

Regarding, local versus dev and prod, that really depends on how much data you like to load on each, and the limits of the system itself. I typically start off with 3 forests per host (kind of a default with Roxy), even for local.

And yes, like Dave said too, I'd encourage reading [Inside MarkLogic Server](https://developer.marklogic.com/inside-marklogic). It goes pretty deep, and has recently been updated to include latest features.

HTH!